# How can you use headsets with separate Audio and Mic cables for Dualshock4?

Tags: ps4, audio-hardware

I am hoping to buy a headset for use on both my pc, and my ps4 - So want one with a 3.5mm jack. I have found some I like, within the price range, and using 3.5mm adapters. However, these headsets have a separate socket for both the audio and the mic. This would be fine for my pc, but the dualshock 4 only has a single 3.5mm jack socket. If I were to use a 3.5mm jack splitter to merge the audio and mic plugs into one, would this work? If not, is there any other piece of equipment that I would be able to use to combine the two leads for mic and audio into one, or is it not possible?

Thank you in advance for any answers!

Comment: You could go for those SONY headsets for the ps3 and ps4 they also work for the PC (windows and mac) and work through the usb port and have great quality. I use mine for just about everything.

Comment: My laptop takes the cell phone headsets and the mic works.  Some PCs may support that.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You'll need to use an audio/mic joiner to join the two separate headphones cable into one, it should look something like this:

[image: audio/mic joiner]

Take note of the [three bands](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phone_connector_(audio)) on the plug and the different colored sockets. This is how you can visually identify the cable has three channels, one for the microphone and two for left and right audio.

A quick [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=3.5+mm+mic+joiner)/[eBay](http://www.ebay.com/bhp/headphone-mic-adapter) search leads to some promising results, just make sure you get the correct cable.

Don't forget to turn on in game audio through the controller port as described in [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/144410/can-i-use-my-regular-3-5mm-headphones-with-a-ps4).

Comment: I just wanted to add, that unless your mic has a mute switch, you'll have to unplug it to mute, because the PS4 does not offer a software mute feature. This is particularly frustrating when you have a headset with built-in mic, want to mute it, but don't want to unplug it, since you'd be unplugging the speakers too.

Comment: What I currently own is a 3.5mm jack splitter, which I have used in the past for creating two audio output sockets on my pc.
It looks almost identical to what is displayed in the image, the only difference being that the two outputs are not labeled separately. Would something like this potentially work for doing the job of an audio/mic joiner, or is there a difference in the wiring that would prevent it working? I also looked on amazon for a joiner and found "3.5mm Jack Headphone/ Earphone OR Mic/ Microphone Splitter" as the only option. Would this work as a joiner (as the name says splitter)?

Comment: A regular headphone splitter would work since what it does is just duplicate the wiring, while what you need is something that "sorts" the two different plugs into a single one (basically a double and single plug into a tree triple plug). A splitter can work as long as it has two female plugs and one male plug. I've found [this one](http://www.amazon.com/gp/aw/d/B006T65CXE?pc_redir=1397559859&robot_redir=1) on a quick Amazon.com search

Comment: In addition, be very careful with what you buy. Adapters for 'apple' headphone/mics WILL NOT work with headsets for android, pc, ps4, ps3, xbox, etc.