# How can I use an Xbox 360 headset through a PS4 controller?

Tags: xbox-360, ps4, audio-hardware

I have an Xbox 360 headset that I'd like to use through a PS4 controller.

It is a 2.5mm connection. Are there connection cables to convert from a 2.5mm to 3.5mm jack?

Comment: I know that 2.5 to 3.5 mm adapters exist, and you could get one for around US$1 online, and I don't believe there's any other obstacles.

Answer (score 3):

**TL;DR: If you adapt the connections, it should work off the bat.** There are a few things to check to make this go smoothly, but **it should be as simple as plug and play**.

#### Check the channels

**2.5mm to 3.5mm adapters are quite common, however, the channels you require make a big impact.** On the Xbox 360 headset, check the plug. Count the rings, and ensure that the adapter has *at least* the same amount. Each ring is a channel. You should expect three; Two for your left and right sound, one for the microphone (or two outputs, one input).

#### Finding the part at a store

**If you wish to go to a physical store, ensure you are heading for an electric wholesaler**. They will charge you considerably less, and are more likely to have the part. All you are having to ask for is a "x channel 2.5mm to 3.5mm adapter".

A lot of people come into my store for that part. As an electric retail store, we only really stock the connection for using them on a plane, and as such, only support 1 channel sound. We also charge 10x the price, because it is in a packet. The same would go for places such as Radio Shack (assuming localisation without further knowledge)

[image: 3-channel 3.5mm plug to 2.5mm socket]

#### Confirming operation

Most of the time these connections follow universal suit, and it should work without problem. [According to this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/144410/can-i-use-my-regular-3-5mm-headphones-with-a-ps4), regular earphones will work for audio, suggesting a better chance. If you have a pair of earphones with a mic (a cheap pair is almost always packaged with mobile phones as a cheap "hands free" solution), plug them in, and see if they work.

As a slightly related point, if your thinking "I don't know where the hell that is! I have a Bluetooth plug for the phone", you will likely find that same Bluetooth works as a headset for the PlayStation 4. (I can only confirm the PS3 supported them, as people used them as cheaper alternatives to the original).